# Improved (with flexbox) old (mailny with float) grid layout that doesn't work in some browsers: gutter not respected

Tags: css, flexbox, cross-browser, grid-layout, gutter

I have just created a grid layout with old techniques (float and inline elements). It works enough nicely. Briefly I have a top-level wrapper class to center and limit size content. There are 2 main sections, each one with a header (20%) ,and the remainder (80%) is subdivided in different ways. There is even an elastic gutter (in em) setted with padding. I have designed the layout with in mind a good separation between content and presentation for high code maintainability and for this rason there is some redundant tag (especially divs).

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Float layout plus wrapping rows using inline-block</title>
  <!-- the base styles and "housekeeping" styles are in here: -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid-base.css">
<!-- the HTML5 shiv, to help older browsers understand styling
 on newer HTML5 elements: -->
 <script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
 <style>
  /* grid styling */
  .row {
    margin: 0 -.6875em;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }
  .row:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
  }
  .row-quartet > * {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .row-trio > * {
    width: 33.3333%;
  }
  .col {
    float: left;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 .6875em 1.375em;
  }
  .col:last-child {
    float: right;
  }
  .row-wrapping {
    font-size: 0;
    margin: 0 -11px;
    margin: 0 -.6875rem;
  }
  .row-wrapping > * {
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

  /* content styling */

  .subcategory {
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8e3339;
  }
  .subcategory-featured {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .subcategory-content {
    width: 80%;
  }
  .subcategory-header {
    width: 20%;
  }

  .story {
    padding: .6875em;
    background-color: #eee;
  }
  .story + .story {
    margin-top: 1.375em;
  }
  .story img {
    width: 100%;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <header class="masthead">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>Important News</h1>

    </div>
  </header>

  <nav role="navigation" class="navbar">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <ul class="navlist">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">World</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Local</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <main class="wrapper">

    <section class="subcategory">
      <div class="row">
        <header class="col subcategory-header">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="col subcategory-content">
          <div class="row row-quartet">
            <div class="col subcategory-featured">
              <article class="story">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300" alt="Dummy image">
                <h3><a href="#">Cras suscipit nec leo id.</a></h3>
                <p>Autem repudiandae aliquid tempora quos reprehenderit architecto, sequi repellat.</p>
              </article>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <article class="story">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300" alt="Dummy image">
                <h3><a href="#">Perferendis, ipsam!</a></h3>
                <p>Neque magnam vero obcaecati facere nobis sint dolore accusamus vitae consequuntur ad necessitatibus, laborum molestiae.</p>
              </article>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <article class="story">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300" alt="Dummy image">
                <h3><a href="#">Curabitur mattis purus nec velit.</a></h3>
                <p>Neque magnam vero obcaecati facere nobis sint dolore accusamus vitae consequuntur ad necessitatibus, laborum molestiae.</p>
              </article>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ul class="row row-quartet row-wrapping">
            <li class="col">
              <div class="story">
                <h3><a href="#">Perferendis, ipsam! Dolor sit amet consectetur</a></h3>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="col">
              <div class="story">
                <h3><a href="#">Aliquam mattis eros id posuere.</a></h3>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="col">
              <div class="story">
                <h3><a href="#">Proin leo felis, semper nec</a></h3>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="col">
              <div class="story">
                <h3><a href="#">Aliquam vitae risus tortor. Sed!</a></h3>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="col">
              <div class="story">
                <h3><a href="#">Perferendis, ipsam!</a></h3>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="col">
              <div class="story">
                <h3><a href="#">Aliquam mattis eros id posuere.</a></h3>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="col">
              <div class="story">
                <h3><a href="#">Proin leo felis, semper nec</a></h3>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="col">
              <div class="story">
                <h3><a href="#">Aliquam vitae risus tortor. Sed!</a></h3>
              </div>
            </li>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="subcategory">
      <div class="row">
        <header class="col subcategory-header">
          <h2>Dolor sit amet</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="col subcategory-content">
          <div class="row row-trio">
            <div class="col">
              <article class="story">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300" alt="Dummy image">
                <h3><a href="#">Ut sit amet mi massa</a></h3>
                <p>Neque magnam vero obcaecati facere nobis sint dolore accusamus vitae consequuntur ad necessitatibus, laborum molestiae.</p>
              </article>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <article class="story">
                <h3><a href="#">Nunc mollis sit amet nunc</a></h3>
                <p>Neque magnam vero obcaecati facere nobis sint dolore accusamus vitae consequuntur ad necessitatibus, laborum molestiae.</p>
              </article>
              <article class="story">
                <h3><a href="#">Duis sed ante enim. Cras</a></h3>
                <p>Neque magnam vero obcaecati facere nobis sint dolore accusamus vitae consequuntur ad necessitatibus, laborum molestiae.</p>
              </article>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <article class="story">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300" alt="Dummy image">
                <h3><a href="#">Animi, explicabo, ipsum</a></h3>
                <p>Neque magnam vero obcaecati facere nobis sint dolore accusamus vitae consequuntur ad necessitatibus, laborum molestiae.</p>
              </article>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>

</body>
</html>
```

And the extern .css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.375;
  font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
  font-family: Avenir Next, Avenir, Franklin Gothic, Trebuchet MS, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 0;
}
a {
  color: #8E3339;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
/* here's our wrapper */
.wrapper {
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 76em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* masthead styling */
.masthead {
  background-color: #8E3339;
}
.masthead h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: -.1em .1em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

/* navbar styling */
.navbar {
  background-color: #5E2126;
  margin-bottom: 1.375em;
}

nav {
  display: block;
}
.navbar ul {
  font-family: 'Avenir Next', Avenir, Corbel, 'Franklin Gothic', 'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #752A2F;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar li {
  float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border-left: 1px solid #8E3339;
}
.navbar li:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}
.navbar li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1.75em;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  color: #fff;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/36q59rav/

To improve the code I introduced in a second moment (A sort of progressive enhancement) the power of flexbox, to add several embellishments as box of equal height that is a tricky feature to have with float (in actual fact there was already flexbox for the navbar with float like fallback).

I'm using Modernizr to test specific flexbox support (class flexbox and flexwrap). I have reached an awesome result in Firefox (for my limited experience) but with my big surprise when I test the code in Google Chrome there is a visual mistake: the second nested row of first section is overlapped to first row and I'm not able to understand why.

Here is the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/rs7n8hLm/

You can see the same problem in the jsfiddle browser.
Advice is also appreciated because I'm in a blind alley, and I'm very available if some line of code is obscure.
Thanks in advance.

Here a screenshot of the problem.
https://ibb.co/jkNKRnY

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Paulie_D It is difficult for me describe the problem with words. It is simpler see the problem executing the second jsfiddle posted. Furthemore , now I'm in Windows OS and I'm watching that with this version of google chrome the code works. In a few time I'm going to post a screenshot with the problem noticed under the google chrome version under Ubuntu OS.

Comment: @Paulie_D      I added a screenshot where you can see the problem: https://ibb.co/jkNKRnY